# How to let a navigation bar fadeout to the top after fading in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know how to make the navigation bar fading into the viewport from the top.

```js
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var x = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(x)

    if (x > 699) {
        $("header").addClass("fix");
    } else {
        $("header").removeClass("fix");
    }
});
```

```css
.fix {
    position: fixed;
    background:#fff;
    -webkit-animation: test .5s linear;
}
.fix + main {
    padding-top: 100px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes test {
    from { top:-100px }
    to { top:0 }
}
```

When it removes the class, it just disappears.
How can i make  fade out back to the top?

I log it into console only for testing. (Yes, i wrote the code, it's not copy paste.)

Comment: Put the transition on the nav element itself and the fix class should only have the different animated property. It looks to me it just animates top, so you can put `transition: top .5s` on the element that needs to be animated, and simply define `top: 0` for the fix class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use keyframes here, a simple `transition` will do the trick

You need to put the position fixed and the original top value on the header itself and only update the animated value when scrolling.

The issue you had before was you had position fixed on the fix class, as soon as you remove the fix class, your element is no longer fixed so it will disappear without any animations. In other words, it can only animate if you had the fix class on it.

https://jsfiddle.net/19qdtL3L/

I edited the scroll value so it will show up sooner

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var x = $(window).scrollTop();
  console.log(x)

  if (x > 300) {
    $("header").addClass("fix");
  } else {
    $("header").removeClass("fix");
  }
});
```

```css
header {
  top: -100px;
  position: fixed;
  transition: top 0.5s;
}

.fix {
  background: green;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>header element</header>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>    <br><br><br><br><br>    <br><br><br><br><br>

<br>sdfdsf
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, is there any reason why you're using Jquery 2.1 and not the newest one ?

Comment: The one I used was the highest one on that code screen, in the fiddle, it is using edge. You can use whichever one you are currently using

Answer (score 0):

Your actual `keyframe` is only going one way : down `(top: -100px to top: 0)`. What you want to do can't work like this.

You could do this without a `keyframe`, only with a `transition` :

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){
  $('div').toggleClass('shown');
});
```

```css
div{
  position: static;
  top: -50px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all .5s;
}

div.shown{
  top: 0;
}

button{
  margin-top:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>

<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: Please explain why it didn't work before and use the OP's code, it's fairly easy to replicate the issue on fiddle

Comment: I added an explanation. My code couldn't be more easy to replicate.

Comment: Your code does not match OP's standard, it's a fixed element when it docked

Comment: The `position` is irrelevant here. We're talking about a navbar, seemingly on top of the page, so `absolute` or `fixed` are the exact same thing.

Comment: That's an oversight on your part. Please look up what position fixed does

Comment: I'll edit my answer, but the `toggle` mechanism still shouldn't have to interfere with the `position`

Comment: The toggle does not have anything to do with this since the OP asked for a scroll. While the logic is good some users might not get the relation because they are newer to js which is why I was suggesting to use OP's code